# Starcraft 2: Do workers (SCVs, probes) lose resources if re-assigned to another job?

Tags: starcraft-2

Let's say I want to build a refinery with an SCV that's currently mining some of that sweet blue mineral.  Coincidentally, the SCV in question has JUST finished his particular mining run and, while moving him to the geyser, we see that he's holding onto mineral.

At this point in time, which of the following is more efficient / common practice among good players?

(i) Telling the SCV to drop off mineral at the command center before proceeding to build a refinery

OR

(ii) Telling the SCV to start building a refinery right away (i.e., no intermediate drop-off at the command center)

The underlying question is as follows: is an SCV (or probe) capable of "stashing away" his mineral while he building the refinery and collecting the first round of gas?

In other words, will he deposit the mineral (which he had when we reassigned him from mining duty to refinery-building duty) at the command center at the same time that he drops off gas for the first time?  Or does he lose the mineral the moment we reassign him?

(I am not really a Zerg player but the question seems less relevant for Zerg anyways given you'd lose the drone when you construct a building.)

Comment: definite duplicate.  my bad.  (i didn't think to search for "drone".)

Comment: "Drone" was a pretty poor term anyhow :)

Comment: I always thought of "Drone" as the Zerg worker, never really think of an SCV or Probe as a "Drone" because... they're not. :P